# Dynamic variable that frees when low on memory?

Tags: c#, .net, variables, memory-management

**Background**

So the premise is that I have a class that provides data with a property.

```
class ExampleClass
{
   string _largeCalculatedVariable = null;
   public string largeCalculatedVariable
   {
       get
       {
           if (_largeCalculatedVariable == null)
           {
              _largeCalculatedVariable = LongRunningCalculate();
           }
           return _largeCalculatedVariable
       }
   }
}
```

The property hides the fact that the data may calculate the data on the fly if it hasn't been generated yet but will return a cached value if it has been precalculated or calculated before.

**Problem**

The problem is that a large list of ExampleClass may be generated and if I access the `largeCalculatedVariable` on enough of them I may run out of memory. Since I can recalculate the value at any time is there a way to tell .NET to drop `_largeCalculatedVariable` when it needs memory?

**Note:** I have a feeling I maybe using the wrong design pattern here.

Comment: Your code is strange.  You can't have Nullable<string> as string is already a nullable type.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? There are some features new to 4.0 that are for this exact situation.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: It's just quick dummy code I wasn't using string in my actual code, code edited

Comment: you're free to accept any answer but isn't @ScottChamberlain answer best suited? MemoryCache is an abstraction/implementation of the WeakReference

Comment: Side note: if you have long complex calculation (or some sort of hard to create object) dropping it due to memory pressure likely not going to help you overall... Creation of complex objects generally require more memory/resources than is consumed by final objects so while you may find some nice solution to caching make sure you really gain anything out of it. Switching to from 32 bit to 64 may solve problem in cheaper way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`WeakReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It allows to keep a reference to some data but tells the `Garbage Collector` to claim that reference if it needs to, which is exactly what you want.

> A weak reference allows the garbage collector to collect an object while still allowing an application to access the object. If you need the object, you can still obtain a strong reference to it and prevent it from being collected.

```
_data = new WeakReference("Hamster");

return _data.IsAlive ? data.Target : CreateData();
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using .NET 4.0 or newer you can use the [`MemoryCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class, you can set it to have rules of how much data it should store and it will clear itself out to make room if it has hit it's limit.

```
class ExampleClass
{
   //This is a static constructor;
   static ExampleClass()
   {
       var settings = new NameValueCollection();
       settings.Add("PhysicalMemoryLimitPercentage", "75");

       _cache = new MemoryCache("ExampleClassCache", settings);
   }

   private static MemoryCache _cache;

   public ExampleClass()
   {
      _cacheKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
   }

   private readonly string _cacheKey;

   public string largeCalculatedVariable
   {
       get
       {
            var record = _cache.Get(_cacheKey) as string;

            //If record was null that means the item was not in the cache.
            if(record == null)
            {
                record = LongRunningCalculate();
                _cache.Add(_cacheKey, record, new CacheItemPolicy(), null);
            }

           return record;
       }
   }
}
```

If you wanted you could also have `ExampleClass` take items out of the cache to free up space when the object is disposed, it would not be much extra to implement.

```
class ExampleClass : IDisposable
{
    //...Everything else is the same from the previous code example.

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true)
        GC.SupressFinialize(this);
    }

    bool _disposed;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if(!_disposed)
        {
            if(disposing)
            {
                //Nothing to do here, we want to remove from the cache if Dispose or the finalizer is called.
                //But you may have IDisposeable objects in your real class, they should be disposed in here.
            }

            if(_cacheKey != null)
                _cache.Remove(_cacheKey, null);

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    ~ExampleClass()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would up vote you but I don't have the necessary rep.

`MemoryCache` is a good fit to the general problem but just because how my existing code is setup I think a `WeakReference` would be more suitable.

Comment: @user3196468 I have re-written my example to make it much more close to your current implementation (Also removed a few errors).

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add, apart from the excellent answers of using **WeakReference** and **MemoryCache** (*the latter might be your better option*) to use the type `Lazy<>`. 
This type already solves any concurrency issues you might have. 
One may think: 'I  Don't have multithreading, why should i care?'

1. Your code is not more complex for using `Lazy<>`
2. Scalability: Once you want to leverage the app to multithread it is already ready.

Starting from .Net 4.0 I always implement a lazy loaded property like this

```
string Lazy<string> _largeCalculatedVariable = null;//No need to set it to null but whatever you prefer
public string largeCalculatedVariable
   {
       get
       {
           if (_largeCalculatedVariable == null)
           {
              _largeCalculatedVariable = new Lazy<string>(()=>
              {
                 _largeCalculatedVariable = LongRunningCalculate();
              }
           }
           return _largeCalculatedVariable.Value
       }
   }
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite what the OP is after. `Lazy<T>` just defers instantiation.. it doesn't free it after it reaches a limit.

Comment: I agree with you. i was just adding some value to the other answers that already refer what he wants: WeakReference and MemoryCache